# Dynamic configuration of a SOAP client anotated with @Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap-client

My Spring Boot application implements a SOAP client like described in the following:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("de.mypackage");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyClient myclient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        MyClient client = new MyClient();
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

Depending on another property `target` I need to configure this `MyClient` object with a different URI, e.g.

- for `target=1` the client must be configured to use `setDefaultUri("http://uri-1")`
- for `target=2` the client must be configured to use `setDefaultUri("http://uri-2")`

I have some trouble understanding how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:**

> // this package must match the package in the  specified in pom.xml
> marshaller.setContextPath("de.mypackage");

You can make use of the maven resources plugin to hardcode maven properties into properties or yaml files using the `@property.name@` syntax. The first step is to add a custom property and refer to the property in the plugin section:

**pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
  <pluginName.generatePackage>de.mypackage</pluginName.generatePackage>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>pluginName</artifactId>
  ...
  <configuration>
    <schemaDirectory>${pluginName.generatePackage}</schemaDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, define a new property in application.properties (or yaml file) and refer to the maven property:

**application.properties**

```
pluginName.generatePackage=@pluginName.generatePackage@
```

**application.yaml**

```
pluginName:
  generatePackage: '@pluginName.generatePackage@'
```

Finally, inject the property into your bean configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller(@Value("${pluginName.generatePackage}") String generatePackage) {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath(generatePackage);
        return marshaller;
    }
```

If you are using the Spring Boot starter parent, you do not need additional configuration to use the above setup. Otherwise you might need to add a bit of resource configuration described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven).

**Regarding your second question:**

> Depending on another property target I need to configure this MyClient
> object with a different URI, e.g.

Once you have obtained the pom.xml property there are many options. If the configuration is not that complex, the bean can be created using a similar String injection and some custom logic in the bean definition, or using conditionalOn* annotations such as:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "target", havingValue="1")
public MyClient myclient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
  // .. bean 1 definition
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "target", havingValue="2")
public MyClient myclient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
  // .. bean 2 definition
}
```

If the bean definition is a bit more complex, consider setting up a [FactoryBean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean).